# WCF service is not multithreaded

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, wcf

I'm designing a WCF service used by a WPF application.
The service will be used by 50 clients and hosted on a multi core server. That's why I would like it to be multi threaded.

This is how I declared it :

```
[ServiceContract(
    SessionMode = SessionMode.Required,
    Namespace = Constants.NameSpace,
    CallbackContract = typeof (ISaphirServiceCallback))]
public interface ISaphirService


[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, 
                InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public partial class SaphirService : ISaphirService
```

And the server side configuration :

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0" receiveTimeout="00:59:00" sendTimeout="00:59:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:30:00" enabled="true"/>
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>

      <customBinding>
        <binding name="ServicePECB2ServiceBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10" />
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://qualiflps.services-ps.ameli.fr/lps" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicePECB2ServiceBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.ServicePECB2Service" name="ServicePECB2Service" />
    </client>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="50" maxConcurrentSessions="50" maxConcurrentInstances="50"/>
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Service.Authorizations.AuthorizationPolicy, Service">
            <authorizationPolicies>
              <add policyType="Service.Authorizations.AuthorizationPolicy, Service" />
            </authorizationPolicies>
          </serviceAuthorization>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://127.0.0.1:80/Service" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="*****" />
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Service.Authorizations.CustomValidator, Service" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0" name="Service.Services.SaphirService">
        <endpoint address="basic" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" contract="ServiceInterfaces.IServices.ISaphirService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="*****" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And here is the client side configuration :

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ISaphirService" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:30:00" enabled="true"/>
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://****:4224/service/basic" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ISaphirService" contract="ISaphirService" name="NetTcpBinding_ISaphirService" behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior">
        <identity>
          <certificate encodedValue="****" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The thing is, each request are processed on the same Thread.
I checked a lot on the Internet but everything seems good to me...

Do you guys have any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: How did you check that? If 50 clients execute the service and you put a sleep into it, do they wait to be processed one after the other?

Comment: How many requests, over what period of time, and what duration?

Comment: I checked with two clients. First it's clearly visible that request #1 from client #2 is waiting the first request from client #1, and as well with some Console.Write( ManagedThreadId )

Comment: So far 20 request from 2 clients, 5 seconds per request

Comment: How is this WCF service hosted (IIS, Windows Service, etc)?

Comment: In a WPF app. Something weird : the UI freeze during long query. Isn't WCF supposed to create threads for each request ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When opening a `ServiceHost` WCF captures the current `SynchronizationContext`, and uses it for all calls. WPF's synchronization context posts every call to the `Dispatcher` queue, which ends up executing on the UI thread.

You have two options:

- Start the service on a different thread that doesn't have a synchronization context. This has the additional advantage of not blocking the UI thread waiting for the service to load. For example, you can use:

  ```
  Task.Run(() => serviceHost.Open());
  ```
- Specify that the service should not use the synchronization context:

  ```
  [ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
  ```

Note that if you modify UI objects in service methods, you might need to dispatch them back to the UI thread yourself.

Comment: Awesome ! One single line of code and everything is smooth now :D Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted your service to maintain some state between calls from the same client then it is worth mentioning `InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession`. Otherwise, you can use `InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall`.

Comment: I do need the session, I'm using a lot of Push request from the service

Comment: I am not sure the level of verification required when simulate 50 client calls. However, ServiceThrottling might be the best place to start. You can also have a look at this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33362/WCF-Throttling

Comment: I think my config is OK regarding ServiceThrottling, isn't it ?