# Can I create a WCF where multiple calls are not blocking each other

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI application that is calling through to a WCF service using an HTTP connection.  The call to the WebAPI is coming from a users browser.  The WCF service is being hosted in a separate IIS application.

Due to some legacy code, one of the methods in the WCF service is a long running process e.g. 30 seconds and it produces a large byte array that we then get back and can pass on.

There is also another method that is not a long running process and should return instantly.  However whilst the client is calling the long process, the other method is blocked from completing until the long process is finished.

I have tried lots of things like adding the following to the service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

and adding the following to the config:

```
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address = "*" maxconnection = "100" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

And turned off Session State:

```
<sessionState mode="Off" />
```

However, I have not been able to get these calls to work in parallel.  I understand that it is something to do with the way that WCF services protect against Session issues but I have turned off `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` and I don't use the HttpContext Session or Cache so I am not sure what is causing the block.

Any ideas on what I can do to get these calls to work in parallel without major re-work to them?

Comment: Have you tried "UseSynchronizationContext = false"?

ref. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22785352/1315873

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Fil but i have tried that but still no luck. The first call is still blocking the second one from starting.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is on the client. WCF calls are blocking, i.e. the client continues its execution only after the service method ends.
If the service method do the long work asyncronously then it can return very soon, the client can continue the execution and (if everything on the server is ok) can call the second (short) WCF method. Maybe two different client calls are executed at the same time (if server is ok) but in this case two calls from the same client have to be done in sequence (waiting the first WCF call to return).

Comment: Try adding _Windows Server AppFabric_ to your IIS deployment.  Then click app; click **Configure...**, and look at the **Throttling** page for **Maximum concurrent calls**

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best of solutions, but I found that setting the reliableSession to false seems to solve the problem under the described circumstances. I personally didn't use it in the end, but I'll post it just in case someone else needs it.

Here's the settings I used within the wcf web.config. Don't forget to also set the reliable session to false on the client side as well.

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BindingName" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
      <reliableSession enabled="false"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
        <message establishSecurityContext="true" clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `ReliableSession` ensures that messages are delivered in the order that they were sent. Check this out: [System.ServiceModel.ReliableSession.Ordered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.reliablesession.ordered)

You need to set `Ordered` to `false`!

Internally it sets the value of the `ReliableSessionBindingElement`. If this still does not work you can also try to set the value of `FlowControlEnabled` of the `ReliableSessionBindingElement` to `false`.